# Помогите решить задачу 'Две строки' на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем привет, учусь программировать на питоне и я запутался в одной тяжелой задаче. При input **AcosbiLeolevB** выводит **AboB**, а должно выводить **ALBivbeslooce**!

У Алисы и Боба есть секретная информация, которая записана в виде строки s. Чтобы сохранить секрет, Алиса сделала перестановку символов в строке по следующему правилу. Она записала все символы строки по кругу, потом записала в ответ первый символ и далее стала выписывать символы из кольца через два.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рассмотрим пример. Пусть секретная строка — **"AliceLovesBob"**. Алиса запишет эту строку, как показано на рисунке. Далее она выпишет первую букву строки **"A"**, пропустит два следующих символа, напишет букву **"c"**, пропустит еще два символа, напишет букву "o" и так далее по кругу. В результате у нее будет записана строка **"AcosbiLeolevB"**. Номера на рисунке слева соответствуют последовательности перечисления букв Алисой.

Боб шифрует эту же строку таким же алгоритмом, однако, в отличие от Алисы, он пропускает по четыре буквы, а не по две. Номера на рисунке справа соответствуют последовательности перечисления букв Бобом. Таким образом Боб получит строку "ALBivbeslooce".

Боб был небрежен и потерял зашифрованную строку, однако, у него есть строка, зашифрованная Алисой. Напишете программу, которая по зашифрованной строке Алисы найдет зашифрованную строку Боба.

**Формат входных данных:**
На вход подается одна непустая строка — шифр Алисы.  Строка состоит только из строчных и заглавных символов латиницы. Длина строки не превосходит `1000` и не кратна трем и пяти.
**Формат выходных данных:**
Выведите одну строку — шифр Боба.

**Sample Input:**

> AcosbiLeolevB

**Sample Output:**

> ALBivbeslooce

А вот мой код:

```py
s = input()

alice_cipher = "" 
bob_cipher = "" 

for i in range(len(s)):
    if i % 3 == 0: 
        alice_cipher += s[i]
    if i % 4 == 0: 
        bob_cipher += s[i]
        
print(bob_cipher)
```

Comment: "А вот мой код" - это хорошо, но в чём ваш вопрос? Ваш код не работает? Ваш код работает не правильно? Это всё должно быть написано прямо в вопросе.

Comment: По сути задача сводится к двум подзадачам: расшифровать строку зашифрованную методом Алисы и зашифровать заново уже методом Боба. Начните с первой.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я же с ней сижу 2 часа, перебираю каждое решение, но ничего не получается, поэтому обратился к вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто найти нужное смещение, здесь оно -7

```
s = input() #'AcosbiLeolevB'

p, l,out = 0, len(s),''
for _ in s:
    out += s[p]
    p = (p - 7) % l

print(out)
```

```
ALBivbeslooce
```

Comment: А где input? Он обязательно должен быть в этой задаче.

Comment: Инпут вернулся :)

Comment: спасибо дружище)